# Несколько яндекс карт в цикле с кнопками. Не работают кнопки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Есть такая проблемка. Выводится какое-то кол-во яндекс карт, сейчас 3, в цикле. Запрещается скролл и перемещение на них. Добавляется кнопка, при нажатии на которую можно двигать карту. Для одной карты работает кнопка. А для нескольких в цикле уже нет. Мозгов не хватает понять в чём дело :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  ymaps.ready(init);

  var maps = [];
  var placemarks = [];
  var centers = [
    [50, 40],
    [50, 40],
    [50, 40],
  ];
  var dragBtns = [];
  var N = $('.bMap').length;

  function init () {
    for (var q = 0; q < N; q++) {
      var ind = q + 1;
      var mapId = 'map' + ind;

      maps[q] = new ymaps.Map(mapId, {
        center: centers[q],
        zoom: 16,
        controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
      });

      maps[q].behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
      maps[q].behaviors.disable('drag');

      placemarks[q] = new ymaps.Placemark(centers[q], {
        hintContent: 'Title',
        balloonContent: ''}, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'img/map-pin.png',
        iconImageSize: [76, 93],
        iconImageOffset: [-38, -67]
      });

      maps[q].geoObjects.add(placemarks[q]);

      // enable/disable drag map
      dragBtns[q] = new ymaps.control.Button('<b>Двигать карту</b>');

      function enableBtn (q) {
        // ПОХОЖЕ ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
        maps[q].behaviors.enable('drag');
      }

      function disableBtn (q) {
        // И ЗДЕСЬ
        maps[q].behaviors.disable('drag');
      }

      dragBtns[q].events
        .add('select', enableBtn(q))
        .add('deselect', disableBtn(q));

      maps[q].controls.add(dragBtns[q], {
        float: "left",
        maxWidth: 155
      });
      // /
    } // /for
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас переменная `q` в [замыкании](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/useful/javascript/lets-learn-javascript-closures). На момент клика по кнопке она уже равна `N`. Залогируйте её или воспользуйтесь отладчиком, чтобы убедиться в этом.

Код придется немного поменять. Самый простой способ - вынести внутренности `for` в функцию, которая будет принимать `q` как аргумент.